# angular2-markdown package works on localhost but when I deploy on GitHub pages it gives me an error

Tags: markdown, github-pages, angular-cli, angular2-ngmodel

### Situation

I develop a site with Angular-CLI and will publish that on GitHub pages. the link to my project is https://heinpauwelyn.github.io.

I've installed a package named [angular2-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-markdown) to render markdown files on my HTML pages. Below you see my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>Internship</h2>
            <!-- Below you see the `markdown` tag to render the markdown file -->
            <markdown path="/reports/intro.md"></markdown>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <app-reportslist></app-reportslist>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To test the site on localhost I use this command:

```
ng serve
```

This command gives no problem and render the markdown files good.

### The problem

An error will be throw when I use command below to deploy my website on GitHub pages.

```
ng github-pages:deploy
```

This gives me next error:

> **ERROR** in `MarkdownModule` is not an `NgModule`

Here is my code in my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 
import { MarkdownModule } from 'angular2-markdown';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MarkdownModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### I've tried

#### Attempt one

I know on the guide stands that I must use `MarkdownModule.forRoot()`. If I use now `ng serve`, I've got this error:

> **ERROR** in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function `MarkdownModule`, function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol `AppModule` in `C:/***/heinpauwelyn.github.io/src/app/app.module.ts`.
>
> **ERROR** in `C:/***/heinpauwelyn.github.io/src/app/app.module.ts`: Property `forRoot` does not exist on type `typeof MarkdownModule`.

#### Attempt two

If I comment the line `export class AppModule()` like in the guide, I got this error:

> **ERROR** in `C:/***/heinpauwelyn.github.io/src/main.ts`: Module `C:/***/heinpauwelyn.github.io/src/app/app.module.ts` has no exported member `AppModule`.
>
> **ERROR** in `C:/***/heinpauwelyn.github.io/src/app/app.module.ts`: Declaration expected.

What is normal of course.

### Question

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 1.3.14 please use the latest version. The current version is 1.3.18

```
npm install angular2-markdown --save
```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: **ERROR in `C:/***/heinpauwelyn.github.io/src/app/app.module.ts`: Cannot find module `angular2-markdown`**. I've deleted my `node_modules` folder and again a `npm install`. Here is the dependencie: `"angular2-markdown": "^1.3.18"` from my `package.json` file.